# How to convert a date say "d/mm/yy" store in a variable to "dd/mm/yy" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, scripting

I have a date stored in one variable in `d/mm/yy` format say `6/09/17`. I want to compare it with date which is in `dd/mm/yy` format e.g., `06/09/17` stored in another variable.

If I directly compare those two variables they are not coming equal, but they should be equal.

Can someone suggest how to convert the date in first variable to the format of date stored in another variable, i.e., from `d/mm/yy` to `dd/mm/yy`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use date to translate to the format you like:

```
date --date="6/09/17" +"%d/%m/%Y"
```

outputs:

```
09/06/2017
```

Comment: date: illegal option -- date=6/09/17
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Answer (score 0):

to compare date they should be converted in iso format yyyy-mm-dd

```
date0=6/09/17
year0=${date0##*/}     # remove longest prefix "*/" = "6/09/" -> "17"
tmp=${date0%/*}        # remove shortest suffix "/*" = "/17"  -> "6/09"
month0=${tmp##*/}      # remove longest prefix "*/" = "6/" -> "09"
day0=${tmp%/*}         # remove shortest suffix "/*" = "/09"  -> "6"

printf -v date1 "%4d-%02d-%02d" "20${year0#0}" "${month0#0}" "${day0#0}"

echo "$date1"
```

or more legible, but maybe less efficient

```
IFS=/ read dd mm yy <<< 6/09/17
printf -v date1 "%4d-%02d-%02d" "20${yy#0}" "${mm#0}" "${dd#0}"
echo "$date1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for this particular case where only the leading zero is missing and you are using Bash, you can use `=~`operator:

```
$ query=6/09/17
$ match=06/09/17
$ [[ $match =~ ^0?$query ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ $query =~ ^0?$query ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Non-match:

```
$ fail=16/09/17
$ [[ $fail =~ ^0?$query ]] && echo yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat="6/09/2017
dat1="06/09/2017"
awk -v dat1=$dat -v dat=$dat '{ split(dat,datarr,"/");split(dat1,datarr1,"/");if (length(datarr1[1])==1) { dat1="0"dat1 } if (length(datarr1[1])==1) { dat="0"dat } if (dat1==dat) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }' <<< ""
if [ "$?" == "0" ]
then
     echo "match"
else
     echo "No match"
fi
```

Use awk to pass the two dates and then split out the day into arrays. Use this to check the length of day and then add 0 to the date variable where necessary. Check that the dates match and exit with a given status accordingly. Check the exit status to judge a match or not.

This solution can also be modified to take account of one digit months as well.